# ios: Coreplot Multiple datasets Have the same data source and overlap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, core-plot

i am trying to display two lines on the same scatter plot. I've successfully put both on one chart. One is green, the other, red.

As of right now, they appear to be pulling from the same data source, thus they are overlapping.

If someone could please tell me how to access the other data in the graphdata, i would greatly appreciate it!

[image]

```
NSArray* data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_graphData];

    NSDictionary*ds1 = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary*ds2 = [data objectAtIndex:1];

    CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    plot.identifier = [ds1 objectForKey:@"PLOT_IDENTIFIER"];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *tyle = [[plot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    tyle.lineWidth = 19.f;
    tyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    tyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0f], nil];
    plot.dataLineStyle = tyle;

    plot.dataSource = self;
    NSLog(@"%@",plot.dataSource);

    [self.graph addPlot:plot];

    CPTScatterPlot *plot2 = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    plot2.identifier = [ds2 objectForKey:@"PLOT_IDENTIFIER"];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tyle2 = [[plot2.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    tyle2.lineWidth = 12.f;
    tyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    tyle2.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0f], nil];
    plot2.dataLineStyle = tyle2;

    plot2.dataSource = self;

    NSLog(@"%@", plot2.dataSource);

    [self.graph addPlot:plot2];
```

Here is the data:

[super viewDidLoad];

```
//This is just so the graph has data without the buttons before them.
data1 = [NSMutableArray array];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-10.5, 8.5)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-10, 29.2)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-9.5, 39.6)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-9, 48.6)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8.5, 47.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8, 51.5)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-7.5, 59.5)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-7, 59.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6.5, 83.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6, 78.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5.5, 120.7)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5, 109.1)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-4.5, 112.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-4, 115.3)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-3.5, 111.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-3, 108.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-2.5, 131.5)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-2, 152.2)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-1.5, 150.2)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-1, 172)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-0.5, 186.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 175.1)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 164.3)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 165)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.5, 159.2)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 146.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2.5, 147.4)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 143.2)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3.5, 153.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 156.7)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4.5, 159.8)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5, 144.5)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 136.1)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6, 107.3)]];
[data1 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6.5, 78.7)]];

//same here
data2 = [NSMutableArray array];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-10.5, 8.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-10, 29.2)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-9.5, 39.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-9, 48.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8.5, 47.8)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8, 51.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-7.5, 59.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-7, 59.4)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6.5, 83.4)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6, 1.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5.5, 15.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5, 19.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-4.5, 20.2)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-4, 16.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-3.5, 15.1)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-3, 16.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-2.5, 19.9)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-2, 19.9)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-1.5, 20)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-1, 23.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-0.5, 28.7)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 30.6)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 28)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 27.2)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.5, 26.7)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 24.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2.5, 23.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 21.7)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3.5, 25.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 23.2)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4.5, 21.2)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5, 144.5)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 136.1)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6, 107.3)]];
[data2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6.5, 78.7)]];



NSDictionary *firstLineDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"firstLine", @"PLOT_IDENTIFIER", data1, @"PLOT_DATA", nil];
    NSDictionary *secondLineDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"secondLine", @"PLOT_IDENTIFIER", data2, @"PLOT_DATA", nil];
    NSMutableArray *dictionarydata = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:firstLineDic, secondLineDic, nil];
     self.scatterPlot = [[psuScatterSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:dictionarydata];
    [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
```

Comment: The objects added to `data1` and `data2` look like they contain the same set of `CGPoint` values. Any reason the points plotted would not overlap?

Comment: data 2 does contain different points than data 1. However, it was not a full set of data points so I copy and pasted the missing data from the first table because I thought it may work? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your datasource. I suspect the datasource methods don't distinguish the plots correctly. Make sure each plot has a unique `identifier` and use that in the datasource to determine which plot is requesting data.